Include null values in SQL constraint
I have a unique constraint on table like this
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS logon (
    login_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
    customer_id   INT NOT NULL,
    sales_id INT,
    UNIQUE (customer_id, sales_id)
);

sales_id can be null.
+-------------+----------+
| customer_id | sales_id |
+-------------+----------+
|           2 |        1 |
|           2 | NULL     |
|           2 | NULL     |
+-------------+----------+

But the DB allows values with null that violates this uniqueness. is there a way to ensure uniqueness of customer_id + sales_id combination with null values?

Do you want to allow only one instance of (2, NULL), or none at all?

@sanurah I created this dbfiddle with your sample data, while the question was still open. It follows the pattern you will find in the accepted answer for the second duplicate post link above, where they discuss options for MySQL 5.7+

@ÁlvaroGonzález I want to allow only one instance

thank you. creating a virtual column with isNull check should work.
